# How does Sony's MagicGate technology work?

Tags: encryption, protection

I own a *Memory Stick Pro Duo Mark-II* (MagicGate compatible). It is used as a storage medium in my **Playstation Portable**.

Upon searching on Google for the same, I only found a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagicGate) page of it, which states:-

> MagicGate is a copy-protection technology introduced by Sony in 1999 as part of the Secure Digital Music Initiative (SDMI). It works by encrypting the content on the device and using MagicGate chips in both the storage device and the reader to enforce control over how files are copied.

And nothing has been explained for *how it does that.*

**How does MagicGate work? What protocols does it use internally?**

**P.S.:** Nothing has been enforced (to my knowledge) as *copy-protection* on the device as all the device files are easily accessible, [emulators](https://www.ppsspp.org/) have been made on its architecture, and the device firmware has already been cracked.

Comment: Companies tend to keep these details a secret for as long as possible so that people don't try to break the proection ...

Comment: Those emulators probably don't have any code to connect to the actual hardware, so they probably don't have any MagicGate-specific code in them.